# React Native FlatList doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

I'm trying to add a searchable list to my React Native app, but encounter a problem whilst trying to render the list itself. The error is the old "You likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports". I'm sure this may be my issue, but after reading several variations of the issue online, I can't seem to figure out where the issue is.

I've tried changing every and any used import in the fashion of listing them one by one, using and removing the brackets. I tried reinstalling react-native-elements, and checked my dependencies for correct versions. Also tried rendering list without data.

List component:
Liste.js

```
import { View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";
import  {List, ListItem }  from "react-native-elements"

class Liste extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

...

 render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <List>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <ListItem
                        roundAvatar
                        title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
                        subtitle={item.email}
                        avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
                    />
                )}
                />
        </List>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Liste;
```

I expected the list to render at all, it doesnt.

Comment: maybe there is an error because react-native-elements library doesn't contain List component.Please see components include in https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements

Comment: can you printscreen the full error message?

Comment: Patels answer was correct. I was referencing old documentation for my usage of the Elements. List used to be supported, but has since been replaced in place of a simple View. Changing this and removing the import worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, you need to remove the `List` component, because the `react-native-elements` does not contain it.
- The second thing that you need to do is to remove `alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center"` from the `View` component.
- Also, in the `FlatList` component, the property `avatar` is wrong. You have to choose between: `leftAvatar` and `rightAvatar`.

You comonent should like look this:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
                roundAvatar
                title={item.title}
                subtitle={item.body}
                leftAvatar={{
                    source: item.thumbnail && { uri: item.thumbnail },
                }}
            />
        )}
    />
</View>
```

Here is a working [demo](https://snack.expo.io/BJmpnqv_N).